# User Roles in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-services

I want to implement user roles for my controller. When the user is admin or master it works, but when the user is a client it doesn't, and I receive a 205 http response.

This code works nicely in my localhost but it doesn't so in my host.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'imageone'=> 'required|string'
    ]);
    if ($validation->fails())
    {

        return response()->json('Fails',404);
    }

    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    if ($user->roles=='admin'||$user->roles=='master') { 
        $name= $request->input('name');
        $imageone = $request->input('imageone');
        $cate=new categoryi();
        $cate->name=$name;
        $cate->imageone=$imageone;

        if ($cate->save())
        {
            return response()->json($cate,202);
        }
     }
    return response()->json('Fails',500);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to happen when user is client? there is no logic for client

Comment: @EddyTheDove i want when user is client show  Fails with 500 code
this code worked in my localhost but in host not work and i've got 205 code

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. But for testing purposes, could you try to implement a logic for that. Like just before the `if($user....)`, could you check first if user is client? and see how it goes.

Comment: @ٍٍEddyTheDove, oh yes  i edited my code but My problem is not resolved

Comment: So it works on local but not online? something to do with environments?

Comment: I do not know what happened , i think problem form host , thanks bro @EddyTheDove